# Creating a custom schema.rb for secondary sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

My default models are using mysql the regular way. but i also have a postgres sql that i am using in my app, and its models look like this:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "postgres_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

part of the yml:

```
postgres_defaults: &postgres_defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost

postgres_development: &postgres_development
  <<: *postgres_defaults
  username: postgres
  password:
  database: houston
```

now, i want to create schema_pg.rb, seed_pg.rb and to be able to create migrations.
i am using gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter' for this.

is there any way i can generate db:schema:dump to other file than schema.rb? and how do i create seeds and migrations for it?